# Prove this function is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x) = \sup_{r>0} \frac{\mu(B_r(x))}{m(B_r(x))}$. Prove it is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ measurable. $\mu$ is a measure on  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\mu(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ is finite, and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

My thoughts: suppose $x \in {f<a}$, then there exists $\epsilon$ s.t. $(1+\epsilon)f(x) <a$. So given some $\delta>0$ for any $x' \in B_{\delta}(x)$ we have

$\frac{\mu(B_r(x'))}{m(B_r(x'))}\leq \frac{\mu(B_{r+\delta}(x))}{m(B_r(x'))} = \frac{\mu(B_{r+\delta}(x))}{m(B_r(x))} = \frac{\mu(B_{r+\delta}(x))}{m(B_{r+\delta}(x))}(\frac{r+\delta}{r})^d \leq f(x)(\frac{r+\delta}{r})^d$

but I need $\delta$ to be uniform in order to prove $\{f<a\}$ is open and I don't know how to treat it when $r$ is very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an $r>0$.
\begin{align*}
x\rightarrow\dfrac{\mu(B_{r}(x))}{m(B_{r}(x))}
\end{align*}
is a lower semi-continuous function. Then, $f$ as the supremum of a class of lower semi-continuous functions, is still a lower semi-continuous function, and hence a Borel function.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if $\mu$ is a delta measure it probably isn't continuous? But it is always lower-semicontinuous so the rest still works

Comment: But for fixed $x_{0}$, the characteristic function $\chi_{B_{r}(x)}(y)\rightarrow\chi_{B_{r}(x_{0})}(y)$ pointwise, so as long as $\mu$ is a finite measure, then $\mu(\chi_{B_{r}(x)})\rightarrow\mu(\chi_{B_{r}(x_{0})})$ by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: What about this example, in $\mathbb{R}$ take $x_0 = 1$ and $r=1$. Then with a delta measure at 0, $\mu(B_r(x_0)) = 0$ but for any$-1 < x < 1$ it is 1.

Comment: Oh you are right. But as a moment of thought I think $\{x:\mu(B_{r}(x))>\alpha\}$ is an open set for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. So $x\rightarrow\mu(B_{r}(x))$ is lower semi-continuous and $m(B_{r}(x))=r^{n}$ is just a constant function, so the resulting function $f$ is lower semi-continuous too.